# How do I iterate through an object using .map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that plays a random sound from the selected array based on which button you push. I want to also give the option of listing all the sounds in an array on demand.

I've been going through all kinds of different suggestions using for loops and .map but I keep running into a wall with the fact being that I can't use .map on an object... I think.

```
class Randomizer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentSound: {name: "laser", sound: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Collision8-Bit.ogg"},
        myArray: [
          {
            name: 'laser',
            sound: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Collision8-Bit.ogg"
          },
          {
            name: 'laugh',
            sound: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Evillaugh.ogg"
          },
          {
            name: 'jump',
            sound: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/jump.ogg"
          }
        ],
        myArraySequel: [
          {
            name: 'laser2',
            sound: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Collision8-Bit.ogg"
          },
          {
            name: 'laugh2',
            sound: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Evillaugh.ogg"
          },
          {
            name: 'jump2',
            sound: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/jump.ogg"
          }
        ]
        }
  }

  newSound(arr){
    this.setState((prevState)=>{
      return {currentSound: prevState[arr][Math.floor(Math.random()*prevState[arr].length)]}
    })
  };



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.newSound('myArray')}}>Sounds from myArray</button>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.newSound('myArraySequel')}}>myArraySequel</button>
        <div>
            Listen! 
            <audio
              autoPlay
              src={this.state.currentSound.sound}>            
            </audio>
            <h2>{this.state.currentSound.name}</h2>           
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>sounds from myArray</h2>
          {/* list of buttons with the name value as the the button name and it will play the sound associated when pressed */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>RandomSoundboard</h1>
     <Randomizer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when I've used .map it's told me to use an array of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this,

the syntax would be like,

```
array.map((element,index)=>(
  <button>{element.name}</button>
))
```

Your code will be like this

```js
{
  this.state.myArray.map((element,index)=>(
      <button>{element.name}</button>
  ))
}
```

Comment: @JoshWren welcome, you can accept my answer  (if it helps you) for future ones